# OkHttp set read timeout. Android

Tags: java, android, okhttp

How can I change read timeout for my OkHttpClient not generally but only for single specific request?

I tried to manage it by interceptors, but interceptors doesn't provide this functionality.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: Please provide some code that you have used for achieving this, Thank You.

Comment: I didn't find the code I needed

Comment: Share your existing code, where you have defined your client and instantiating your request objects, etc. So that we can suggest a specific solution.

Comment: You did not understand. I have no the problem code. I mere have no code, because I don't know what code can solve my  task. Posting current client definition doesn't make a sense, it contains not a needed code

Comment: I think there is no such feature in OkHttpClient . Do you asking for a workaround?

Comment: If there is no right solution, then I can apply a workaround

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `OkHttpClient.newBuilder()`. From [the official Javadoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html):

> You can customize a shared OkHttpClient instance with newBuilder(). This builds a client that shares the same connection pool, thread pools, and configuration. Use the builder methods to configure the derived client for a specific purpose.

Their example seems to do exactly what you're trying to do:

```
OkHttpClient eagerClient = client.newBuilder()
    .readTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();
```

Comment: That change will influence to the all requests

Comment: @P.Ilyin No, it will not. Any requests you do with `eagerClient` (which might be only a single request, if you want) will use the new timeout, but any requests you make with your existing `client` will not be affected.

Comment: Now I see, you suggest to create separate OkHttpClient for separate Api, ok, applied.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.build();
```

Comment: This code overrides timeouts for whole app's requests, not for special one